# Why does `userEvent.click` not trigger a form submission with Vitest and React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, vitest

The following test runs and passes just fine when using Create React App out of the box.

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import App from "./App";

describe("Update the name", () => {
  it("updates the name", () => {
    render(<App />);
    userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/name/i), "John");
    userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button"));

    expect(screen.getByText("John")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

So, the test itself should be just fine. Yes, there is only 1️⃣ button, and that is `type="submit"`. App works when running in browser and tests are fine in Create React App (CRA).

I am trying to move to Vitest (with Vite). Theoretically, no changes should be necessary to the above test. However, here's what happens: `TypeError: target.ownerDocument.createRange is not a function`.

Let's get to the configurations.

`vite.config.js` looks  like this:

```js
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "happy-dom",
    setupFiles: "./src/setup.js",
  },
});
```

`./src/setup.js` looks like this: `import "happy-dom";`

Yes, I also tried with `jsdom`.

I also replaced `userEvent.click` with `fireEvent.click`. I also added a `data-testid` to my form and tried `fireEvent.submit` directly on that form.

In the latter scenarios, no errors but either the form submit wasn't triggered, or the submission was triggered, but the render was not updated.

Fact of the matter is if the  works in CRA, then the test should not have to be changed. Possibly only the configurations.

I love Vite, but can't continue with it if I can't get the testing ✅ experience working.

Comment: userEvents are async methods. try using `await userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/name/i), "John");
    await userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button"));`. To make it work the `it` callback should be `async` as well

Comment: Yeah. Got that figured a while ago. Forgot to post back. Tx.

Comment: Doesn't solve it for me. I'm migrating from Jest to Vitest and facing the same problem. I'm already await'ing and my test function is async. It works in Jest.

Comment: Have a snippet to look at? Actually, since this time, I've been using Cypress more than React Testing Library and much less 'game playing' with `await`s and such. Cypress is smart enough to behave like the user and automatically 'await.'

Comment: Just faced with the same problem. Did you fix that?